# Inter Column Calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which have 4 columns

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Math', 'Geo', 'Total', 'Difference'])
```

Can anyone please tell me how can i write this function____

```
data['Total'] = data['Math'] + data['Geo']
data['Difference'] = data['Math'] - data['Geo']
print(data)
```

In something like this way_____

```
row = {"Total": data['Math']+data['Geo'], "Difference": data['Math'] - data['Geo']}
print(data)
```

I know this is wrong way cause I'm getting error like this____

```
Series([], dtype: object)
```

Thank you in advance :) :) :)

Comment: What is error? Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Series([], dtype: object) error

Comment: So there is emty DataFrame and need processing it? there are no rows?

Comment: I'm using for loop to fetch data from online and feed into dataframe

Comment: hmm, so please add sample data of second Dataframe with data. also expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that returns a series, which adds your two columns using apply().

```
def fcn(row):
    return pd.Series([
    row['Math']+row['Geo'], 
    row['Math']-row['Geo']
    ])
    
data[['Total','Difference']] = data.apply(fcn,axis=1)
```